# Remove ordered currency from magento admin

Tags: magento

Does anyone know a quick way to remove the ordered currency from the order summary detail and order mail?
I am having Sage pay currency conversion issue. So the base currency and ordered currency have the same value. So I want to remove ordered currency from order mail and order details
For example at the moment on our multi store setup we have order summary displaying like so:

```
Grand Total £447.60
       [€447.60]
```

Here £447.60 value is correct but the conversion to euro is not correct. So we want to display the totals in just the base currency.